# Is there any way to compile multiple C# files in to multiple assembly with circular dependency?

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly

I got for example two classes cross referencing each other. I want to compile these files to separate dll files.

File 1:

```
public class A
{
    public B bObj;

    public A () 
    {
        bObj = new B (this);
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

File 2:

```
public class B 
{
    public B (A aObj)
    {
        aObj.TestMethod ();
        aObj.bObj.CallMyself ();
    }

    public void CallMyself()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to be able to share only the parts of the project with other people that they are working on. They need to be able to test it out, so they have to compile to project. Is there any magic solution that can be easily automated? The solution should work on any file, I know how to resolve circular dependency with a 3rd assembly.

As I mentioned, I know how to resolve a situation like this. I just wrote a nasty example, to show that I want to create a solution that can deal with any code.

Comment: This doesn't look right...

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with that logic; This is definitely an example of the XY Problem.  You have an unknown *problem* which has led you to a design decision *solution* that involves circular references.  Instead of asking how to solve the *problem*, you've asked how to make the *solution* easy to use, except this solution is one of the worst design concepts you could ever conceive.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: I agree with @Claies. You should follow Ashley Frieze's advice on creating interfaces for your classes, and look into [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Did you guys read the bottom part too?

Comment: aagocs, the fact that want to do that does not make it any better idea as @Claies pointed out. Nice entertainment, educational or prank project, but if you want to do it for actually useful code than using proven techniques will give others chance to understand code in reasonable amount of time. `A(B b)` and `B(A a)` are hard to reason about by itself already, adding crazy assembly split not going to make it more understandable.

Comment: "I want to create a solution that can deal with any code.".....  The whole purpose of the compiler detecting issues like this in the first place is to encourage you to fix these problems, rather than have nasty impossible to find bugs appear in production code.  Trying to circumvent the compiler only encourages you to not fix the problem; This is like the surgeon that sews a tool inside a person and hopes they don't get a lawsuit....

Answer (score 4):

- Compile B.dll with `class B` changed to remove dependency on A
- Compile A.DLL with B.dll and `class A` depending on B
- recompile B.DLL with complete `class B`

If interfaces of classes don't change you may be able to recompile just one without source of another.

Should you go this route - no.

Comment: Plus one *Should you go this route - no.*

Comment: If I remove the dependency from B to A, the constructor in this case will be empty, so A can't construct type B with a parameter type A.

Comment: @aagocs you may need to do more iterations till you get both tied up completely... or to shorten the cycle make constructors to take `object` so there is no dependencies in signatures of the classes... I really hope you doing it to have revenge on someone and not in an effort to improve and simplify code. :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is don't do this. In this situation, it's common to put common interfaces in a separate library that everyone can see, so they can program to those interfaces without affecting each other, and then put the private stuff in separate assemblies that rely on the first.

E.g.

```
// myproject.interfaces.dll
interface IA 
{
    void Process(IB b);
}

interface IB
{
    void Process(IA a);
}

// myproject.A.dll - depends on myproject.interfaces.dll
class A : IA
{
    ....
}
```